# Linearly equivalent divisors are numerically equivalent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a field. Is there a direct way of seeing why every pair of linearly equivalent divisors $D_1$ and $D_2$ is numerically equivalent? I simply found myself unable to pass from the first definition below to the other.

Recall that $D_1 \sim D_2$ linearly if they differ by a prime divisor, and $D_1 \sim D_2$ numerically if they have the same intersection number against every curve in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D_1\sim D_2$ is equivalent to $D_1-D_2\sim 0$, and the intersection number is additive, we can focus in the case $D\sim 0$, i.e., $D=\operatorname{div}(f)$.

If, $X$ is a curve, it it true since $\deg(\operatorname{div}(f))=0$.
Now, if $X$ is a surface, we have to show that $D\cdot\operatorname{div}(f)=0$ for any divisor $D$ on $X$, but it is enogh to show it in the case where $D=C$ is a curve. In this case, we have that $C\cdot \operatorname{div}(f)=\deg(\operatorname{div}(f)|_C)=0$ since $\operatorname{div}(f)|_C$ is again a principal divisor.
For the general case $\dim(X)\geq 3$, we can reduce it to the surfaces case. For example, if $\dim(X)=3$, the statement to show  is that if $D$ is principal, then
for any pair of divisor $D_1$, and $D_2$,
$$D_1\cdot D_2\cdot D=0.$$
Here, we can note that $D_1\cdot D_2\cdot D=D_1|_{D_2}\cdot D|_{D_2}=0$ (is the surface case). Clearly, we assume that $D_1$  and $D_2$ are prime divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Linear equivalence on any $X$ is induced (by definition) by linear equivalence of points on $\mathbb{P}^1$, and while numerical equivalence of points on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is obvious, it implies numerical equivalence of linearly equivalent divisors.